# WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); is showing The constructor ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions) is undefined

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Is showing `The constructor ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions) is undefined`, why?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers.Please do not post your code as Image. Please see how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that demonstrates your problem. Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour , visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help and especially read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Try to close eclipse and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Save the code after importing the below statement `Try to import "org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver".`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the webdrivermanager. 
You can find more details and examples on link below.

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager